# Reverse DNS, who sets this up

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange

I have 4 domains registered with an online host, all these domains have been setup with both A & MX records pointing at our office WAN Static IP, behind that I have an Exchange Server. This had been working fine until this week when I had to change our WAN Static IP.

I updated the DNS on the domain hosting simply replacing the old IP with the new one, this was over 72 hours ago.

Now when our users send to certain domains they are being bounced due to 'no reverse dns' checking this at MX tools does indeed confirm that.

What I am struggling with is who can manage the reverse DNS, is it the domain manager [me] or the company who provide the WAN Static IP [UK ISP, Viatel]. I cant recall ever asking anyone to add reverse DNS entries for me in the past?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you reverse-lookup your old IPs? Do you still get the names of the servers?

Answer (score 9):

The netblock owner is authoritative for the reverse lookup zone for the ip address (unless they've delegated it to another entity). This is normally the ISP that allocates the ip address to you, so start there.

Answer (score 0):

The ISP will be able to set this up for you. Normally I would give them a call tell them what you want setting up and ask them if they have an email address you can send the request through to (normally a support@ address).